# Open modalPanel with a parameter

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'd like to have modal panel in a page, but I would like to be able to supply a parameter.
Now I do it like this:

Panel:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="panel" width="500" height="435">
  ...
  [#{bean.tempId}]
</rich:modalPanel>
```

button to open panel:

```
<ui:repeat ... var="item">
  <h:form>
    <a4j:commandLink id="link" oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('panel');" reRender="panel">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item.id}" target="#{bean.tempId}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
      text...
    </a4j:commandLink>
  </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

This doesn't seem to be the best approach. What would be a better one?

Comment: so you want this parameter to go to the server, not just stay on the client?

Comment: No, I don't want it to go the server. It seems to be pointless to go the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want it to go to the server, it is not so much JSF related. in `oncomplete` you can assign the value to a javascript variable and use that variable in the panel.